# Reading from an encrypted file into a declared string variable

Tags: java, android, encryption, fileinputstream

I have an encrypted file that was done using reference from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256-bit-aes-password-based-encryption/992413#992413) .I got the file encrypted.Now my issue is when trying to read the contents out, am getting an empty strings from the returned `read()`. Below is my call method and the method to decrypt the encrypted text to a string variable.

**Calling Method:**

```
File encryptedCFG = new File(homeDir + "/" + folder_name + "/twCGF.txt");
dc.ReadEncryptedFile(encryptedCFG);
```

**Method:**

```
public void ReadEncryptedFile(File deInFile) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(deInFile);
            int length = (int) deInFile.length();
            byte[] filebyte = new byte[length]
            // Decrypt the byte contents from the file using the cipher setup
            byte[] tmpTxT = mDecipher.doFinal(filebyte);
            fis.read(tmpTxT);
            fis.close();

         // Read into a string since we got the contents
         String plaintxt = new String(tmpTxt, "UTF-8");

         } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Any pointers why am not getting the contents of the encrypted file correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the line where you're decrypting the byte array, it's still empty. You haven't read the file in, yet. You have to switch the operations.

```
byte[] filebyte = new byte[length]
fis.read(filebyte);
byte[] tmpTxt = mDecipher.doFinal(filebyte);
fis.close();

String plaintxt = new String(tmpTxt, "UTF-8");
```